# ConcurrentSkipListSet вставка Java 6

Tags: java

Вопрос по ConcurrentSkipListSet в **Java 6**

Есть такой вот код.
После вставки в сет результат имеет такой вид:

*sout* user.getId(): 
12
15
12

Почему так? Ведь должен быть 12, 15.

```
 сlass Comp implements Comparator<UserModelTmp>
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(UserModelTmp o1, UserModelTmp o2)
        {
            if (o1.getUserId() == o2.getUserId())
            {
                return 0;
            }
            return o2.getTime().compareTo(o1.getTime());
        }
    }


Set<UserModelTmp> set = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<UserModelTmp>(new Comp());

private void add()
{
  set.add(new UserModelTmp(12, System.currentTimeMillis()));
  set.add(new UserModelTmp(12, System.currentTimeMillis()+122));
  set.add(new UserModelTmp(15, System.currentTimeMillis()+144));
  set.add(new UserModelTmp(12, System.currentTimeMillis()+166));
}

public class UserModelTmp
{
    int userId;
    Long time;

    public UserModelTmp(int userId, long time)
    {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.time = time;
    }


    public UserModelTmp(int userId)
    {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.time = 0L;
    }

    public int getUserId()
    {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId)
    {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public Long getTime()
    {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(long time)
    {
        this.time = time;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        UserModelTmp that = (UserModelTmp) o;

        return userId == that.userId;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return userId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Почему должен быть?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите добавлять только уникальных по id UserModelTmp, необходимо изменить компоратор, например:

```
class Comp implements Comparator<UserModelTmp> {
    @Override
    public int compare(UserModelTmp o1, UserModelTmp o2) {
        return o1.getUserId() - o2.getUserId();
    }
}
```

Я бы еще изменил hashCode

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
   return Objects.hash(userId);
}
```

Comment: Хеш код пробовал - не помогает. А вот компаратор по сути ничего с уникальностью не изменит. У меня же там проверка на userId. Если они равные, то я возвращаю 0. Это равносильно o1.getUserId() - o2.getUserId(); Если они не равные, то  я хочу отсортировать по времени.

Comment: @cartman, отвечая на ваш вопрос, почему в set попали элементы с одинаковым id, но с разным временем, ведь мы же переопределили equals и hashCode: потому что в данной коллекции (а точнее map которая под капотом) при добавлении элементов учитывается ещё и компоратор.